# How to combine two regular expressions in JavaScript validation

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

```js
function checkpara(obj) {

  var paragraph = obj.value;
  var para = /\d{4}/;
  if (paragraph.match(para)) {

    document.getElementById("para_error").innerHTML = " You can't use numbers in description";
    document.getElementById("para_error").className = "errmsgshow";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("para_error").className = "errmsghide";
  }

}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.w_50 {
  width: 400px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.errmsghide {
  display: none;
}

.errmsgshow {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <textarea id="para" name="desc" rows="20" cols="66" onblur="checkpara(this)"></textarea>
        <span id="para_error" class="errmsghide"></span>

      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

I have used JavaScript to validate the paragraph. The paragraph should not contain more than 4 sequences of numbers (i.e 1234).

I want in this format.
4 sequence number space 4 sequence number.
Then it should show error message.
How can I combine the two regular expressions?

Comment: Can you give us an example list of what strings that would test as a match and what strings would test with no match. Please provide a few because I don't really understand your specification.

Comment: In a paragraphp If sequence of 3 numbers ocuur means error will occur.For this I used /d{4}...Similarly I want 1234 space 1234 then error should occur.for this I need something like this \d{4} /s \d{4}.how to combine this?

Comment: I still don't understand. You need a regular expression to match what string? Give some examples of the strings that would match and some examples of strings that would NOT match.

Comment: a number.a number should not exceed more than 3

Comment: If you only want to ensure the digits do not exceed 4 then you can use `/^\d{0,4}$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need this: `/\d{4}( \d{4})?/`

Or for *n* sequences: `/\d{4}( \d{4})*/`

Comment: Yeah .This is wat I need.Thank you for your answer